# How do I remove extra spacing on a new page following an align*?

Tags: spacing, align, page-breaking

I have the following code:

```
%...
\begin{proof}
  Let $P=(x_P, y_P, z_P)$ be a fixed point on the plane, $R$ a fixed length, and $X=(x,y,z)$ a
  variable point such that $XP=R$. As $X$ varies, it is obvious that it does so along a circle.
  Obviously, we have the displacement vector $\vv{XP}=(x_P - x, y_P - y, z_P - z)$.
  Using \ref{distance}, it follows that

  \begin{align*}
    & XP^2 = - \sum_{cyc} a^2 (y_P - y)(z_P - z) \\
    \Leftrightarrow & R^2 = -\sum_{cyc} y_P z_P a^2 + \sum_{cyc} y_P a^2 z
    + \sum_{cyc} z_P a^2 y - \sum_{cyc} a^2 yz \\
%...
```

And the following output is produced:

[image]

You may notice that there is more spacing than the default 1 inch margin at the top of the new page. It also happens that if I remove the extra space before the beginning of the align* sequence, the last sentence of the last page appears in the next page, filling the extra space. How do I remove this extra space?

Comment: never leave a blank line before a displayed equation (whether `\[` or `equation` or `align` etc), it will _always_ make bad spacing.

Comment: When that blank line is removed, the page breaking is controlled by two parameters: `\predisplaypenalty` (usually 10000) for a break before the display and `\displaywidowpenalty` (usually 50) for a break before the last line above the display. Since 10000 is effectively infinite, the previous line stays with the display. You could temporarily set `\predisplaypenalty=0` to allow a page break before the display.

Answer (score 2):

I did the best I could with no MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{41\baselineskip}

  Let $P=(x_P, y_P, z_P)$ be a fixed point on the plane, $R$ a fixed length, and $X=(x,y,z)$ a
  variable point such that $XP=R$. As $X$ varies, it is obvious that it does so along a circle.
  Obviously, we have the displacement vector $\vec{XP}=(x_P - x, y_P - y, z_P - z)$.
  Using \ref{distance}, it follows that 
  \pagebreak[3]
  \begin{align*}
    & XP^2 = - \sum_{cyc} a^2 (y_P - y)(z_P - z) \\
    \Leftrightarrow & R^2 = -\sum_{cyc} y_P z_P a^2 + \sum_{cyc} y_P a^2 z
    + \sum_{cyc} z_P a^2 y - \sum_{cyc} a^2 yz \\
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```